# m2eclipse crashes eclipse 3.5.SR2 running on openjdk-6-jdk

Tags: m2eclipse, java

I downloaded the latest version of `eclipse` (3.5.SR2) and get `m2eclipse` installed on.

Instead of running on `sun-jdk-6` (which is obsolete for the recent `Ubuntu 10.04 alpha`), I have eclipse running on open-jdk-6.

Everything was just fine. I can open my existing project and have them compiled as well as running tests.

However, with m2eclipse installed on, my eclipse will crash every time I start it.

If I stopped the m2eclipse plugin from contacting the central repo, then eclipse will continue to run normally.

The craziest point is that eclipse will exit immediately as soon as the contacting to central repo finish, but leave no track in the log.

What should I do right now?

Comment: Well, I go to sun website, download sun jdk 1.6.8.2 from there and set it as the runtime env for eclipse. `m2eclipse` works fine now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I was having the same problem. Was driving me crazy. (Ubuntu 10.04). I modified my eclipse.ini to be as follows (NOTE: I have /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun as a soft-link to /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun-1.6.0.20) - NOTE the "-vm" line and following line:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.201.R35x_v20090715.jar
-vm
/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.0.200.v20090519
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.reporting.product
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx1024m
```

Now everything works great! Thanks all for the help!

Answer (score 0):

confirming the exact same problem!

.. and the solution, using Sun JDK 1.6 Update 17 x64 eclipse runs fine now.

System:
Intel Core 2 Duo,
Ubuntu 10.04 x64

Answer (score 0):

I created https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-2241 for this issue. As reported by running "eclipse -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java" instead.

Answer (score 0):

Me too: running `eclipse -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/bin/java` once fixed the problem, and allowed Maven to update correctly. Since doing that, it seems that using openjdk is fine again.

Comment: Actually this only works for a week, then the problem recurs.